# Solving the comparison equation $y^{\prime \prime \prime}-x y^{\prime}-\mu y=0$ when $\mu=\frac{3}{4}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the [comparison equation](https://archive.org/details/airyfunctionsapp0000vall/page/106/mode/2up) from Airy Functions and Applications to Physics by Vallee and Soares

$$y^{\prime \prime \prime}-x y^{\prime}-\mu y=0$$
when $\mu=\frac{3}{4}$.

---

When $\mu=\frac{1}{2}$ this equation has general solution
$$
y_{1 / 2}=a \mathrm{Ai}^2\!\left(2^{-2 / 3} x\right)+b \mathrm{Bi}^2\!\left(2^{-2 / 3} x\right)+c \mathrm{Ai}\!\left(2^{-2 / 3} x\right) \mathrm{Bi}\!\left(2^{-2 / 3} x\right)
$$

When $\mu=1$

$$y_1=a \mathrm{Ai}(x)+b \mathrm{Bi}(x)+c\mathrm{Hi}(x).$$

In general,

[image]

The above image does give me the solution when $\mu =\frac{3}{4}$, but it is in terms of contour integrals that I am not sure how to evaluate as I don't think the parameterizations of those curves are nice. How can I solve the equation more explicitly in this case of $\mu=\frac{3}{4}$?

Here is a link to the reference [Airy Functions and Applications to Physics](https://archive.org/details/airyfunctionsapp0000vall/page/108/mode/2up) page 108 in the first edition. The page prior has the comparison equation stated.

---

EDIT: I am looking for an answer more explicit than the one terms of hypergeometric functions given by Mathematica, similar to the case of $\mu = \frac{1}{2},1$.

Wolfram spits out

$$
 y(x)=c_1\frac{\sqrt[3]{-1} x_1 F_2\left(\frac{7}{12} ; \frac{2}{3}, \frac{4}{3} ; \frac{x^3}{9}\right)}{3^{2 / 3}}+ c_2
{}_1 F_2\left(\frac{1}{4} ; \frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3} ; \frac{x^3}{9}\right)+c_3\frac{(-1)^{2 / 3} x^2{ }_1 F_2\left(\frac{11}{12} ; \frac{4}{3}, \frac{5}{3} ; \frac{x^3}{9}\right)}{\sqrt[3]{3}}
$$

but I require something more explicit stated not in terms of hypergeometric functions, but maybe something involving $\operatorname{Ai}, \operatorname{Bi}$.

Thank you

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y%27%27%27-xy%27-3%2F4y%3D0) is your friend.

Comment: @Gonçalo It's expressed in terms of hypergeometric functions which is not a simplified form. Wolfam also expresses the above cases in terms of hypergeometric functions but they can be simplified in terms of Ai and Bi.

Comment: What's the source of the image you have embedded?

Comment: @person The book is "Airy functions and applications to physics
by Vallée, Olivier, 1947" page 108 in the first edition and I think 120 in the second. Here is a link to the exact page.  https://archive.org/details/airyfunctionsapp0000vall/page/108/mode/2up

Comment: @Aruralreader Great question! I am not sure. This is the name given to it with no explanation in Airy functions and applications to physics by Vallée, Olivier, linked above.

Comment: Does the solution in the form of infinite series help?

Comment: @MohamedMostafa that would be effectively the same as hypergeometric functions

Comment: Airy functions are particular hypergeometric functions. In other words for some particular values of the parameters of the hypergometric function this function reduces to Airy functions. Thus it is not surprising that for some particular values of the parameter $\mu$ of the ODE the solution involves Airy functions and in the general case (any $\mu$) the general solution involves hypergeometric functions. It is a logical error to think that Airy functions in a particular case implies Airy functions in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, solutions are linear combinations of products of three rescaled Airy functions.

One way of getting there is by Fourier transform. You won’t get all the solutions since they are not all tempered because of their exponential blowup at infinity. I’ll use the convention:
$$
\begin{align}
y(x)&=\int \hat y(k)e^{ik x}\frac{dk}{2\pi} & \hat y(x)&=\int y(x)e^{-ik x}dx 
\end{align}
$$
Your equation:
$$
y’’’-xy’-\mu y=0
$$
becomes in Fourier:
$$
(ik)^3\hat y+(k \hat y)’-\mu\hat y=0
$$
which you can solve:
$$
\hat y\propto k^{\mu-1} e^{ik^3/3}
$$
so you already have a solution, $y$ is the $\mu$-th (fractional) derivative of $\text{Ai}$. Any other two linearly independent solutions are not tempered.

It turns out that in your special case, you can write the $3/4$-th derivative as a cube of Airy just as the $1/2$-th derivative is a square of Airy.

You can also see this in Fourier space. Real space point-wise product become convolution products in Fourier space. Convolution products of Airy functions are not hard because they are just gaussian integrals. You can check that:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal F\text{Ai}^2 &= \int \exp\left(\frac i3(l^3-(k-l)^3)\right)\frac{dl}{2\pi} \\
&= e^{-ik^3/3}\int e^{-ik(l^2-kl)}\frac{dl}{2\pi}\\
&\propto e^{-ik^3/3}k^{-1/2}e^{ik^3/4}\\
&\propto \frac{e^{-i(2^{-2/3}k)^3/3}}{k^{1/2}}
\end{align}
$$
which is how you can recover the solution $\text{Ai}(2^{-2/3}x)^2$ for $\mu=1/2$.

For your problem, you just need to do another convolution product. You just need to be careful with the rescaling so that you have the same cancellation of the cubes:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal F[\text{Ai}^2(2^{-2/3}x)\text{Ai}(x)] &\propto \int l^{-1/2}\exp\left(\frac i3(l^3-(k-l)^3)\right)\frac{dl}{2\pi} \\
&\propto e^{-ik^3/3}\int l^{-1/2}e^{-ik(l^2-kl)}\frac{dl}{2\pi}\\
&\propto e^{-ik^3/3}k^{-1/4}e^{ik^3/4}\\
&\propto \frac{e^{-i(2^{-2/3}k)^3/3}}{k^{1/4}}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, you get the solution:
$$
y\propto\text{Ai}(2^{-4/3}x)^2\text{Ai}(2^{-2/3}x)
$$
You get the other two solutions by switching $\text{Ai}$ with $\text{Bi}$.

Recursively, setting $\nu=\mu-1$, if you know a solution for $\nu_1,\nu_2$, then you also have it for:
$$
\nu=-\frac{1+\nu_1+\nu_2}2
$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you actually "switch Ai with Bi" to get exactly two more solutions? I suppose we could introduce complex arguments for Ai instead, using branches of the cube root, but this would leave us with having to resolve real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a solution in series as $y = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k x^k$ we obtained the following representation:

$$
y = c_1f_1(x,\mu)+c_2f_2(x,\mu)+c_3f_3(x,\mu)
$$

with

$$
\cases{
f_1(x,\mu) = \sum_{k=0}^{k=n}\frac{\Pi_{j=0}^{k-1}(\mu+3j)}{(3k)!}x^{3k}\\
f_2(x,\mu) = \sum_{k=0}^{k=n}\frac{\Pi_{j=0}^{k-1}(\mu+3j+1)}{(3k+1)!}x^{3k+1}\\
f_3(x,\mu) = \sum_{k=0}^{k=n}\frac{\Pi_{j=0}^{k-1}(\mu+3j+2)}{(3k+2)!}x^{3k+2}\\
}
$$

I hope this helps.

NOTE

Included a MATHEMATICA script showing the agreement between the theoretical and the approximate solutions.

```
f1[x_, mu_, n_] := Sum[1/((3 k)!) Product[mu + 3 j, {j, 0, k - 1}] x^(3 k), {k, 0, n}]
f2[x_, mu_, n_] := Sum[1/((3 k + 1)!) Product[mu + 3 j + 1, {j, 0, k - 1}] x^(3 k + 1), {k, 0, n}]
f3[x_, mu_, n_] := Sum[2/((3 k + 2)!) Product[mu + 3 j + 2, {j, 0, k - 1}] x^(3 k + 2), {k, 0, n}]
d[y_, x_] := D[y, x, x, x] - x D[y, x] - mu y
x0 = 0;
y0 = 1;
dy0 = 1;
ddy0 = -1;
soly = DSolve[{d[y[x], x] == 0, y[x0] == y0, y'[x0] == dy0, y''[x0] == ddy0}, y, x][[1]];
yx = y[x] /. soly;

n0 = 8;
Yn = c1 f1[x, mu, n0] + c2 f2[x, mu, n0] + c3 f3[x, mu, n0];
equ1 = (Yn /. {x -> x0}) - y0;
equ2 = (D[Yn, x] /. {x -> x0}) - dy0;
equ3 = (D[Yn, x, x] /. {x -> x0}) - ddy0;
solc = Solve[{equ1 == 0, equ2 == 0, equ3 == 0}, {c1, c2, c3}][[1]];
Yn0 = Yn /. solc;

gr1 = Plot[(yx /. {mu -> 3/4}), {x, -5, 4}, PlotStyle -> {Blue}];
gr2 = Plot[(Yn0 /. {mu -> 3/4}), {x, -5, 4}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}];
Show[gr1, gr2]
```

[image]